# Proper way to analyse purchase data

Tags: regression

I have a dataset containing information about various factors influencing the amount purchased of different products.

factors include the number of people who bought it, the degree to which the product was on sale (90 or 80%), the number of times the product was on sale, etc.

I would like to see how much such factors influence the popularity of each product (number of people buying it)

I was wondering if a simple regression or anova would do the job or whether there are some other specific statistics more suitable for such problems.

further problems: I have data from different companies offering different products. I want to make inferences about the relationship between the type of product and the amount purchased by pooling all the data available from the different companies. However, my problem is that the different companies differ in size and therefore the amount they have sold. Can this be solved somehow?

Comment: Do you have individual level information or only aggregate information?

Comment: @tards I have individual level information = information about each product and its corresponding factors

Comment: I meant do you have information at the level of a consumer? Perhaps, a small sample of (2 or 3 rows) would be useful.

Comment: I only know how many consumers bought each product and whether they bought multiple products and whether they returned at a later time

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do tests for heteroscedasticity and multicollinearity. Then you could run a multitude of regression models which you would read up on to see which fits best, ARCH, OLS, GARCH...And if IIRC, you either take the log of the dependent variable or the log of all the variables so that when you take your regression, the coefficients give you the percent effect (influence) of each independent variable.

Comment: Could you suggest any books that discuss these kinds of topics? Thanks.

Comment: ummm not off the top of my head but a good Econometrics textbook is what you need.  Sorry but I took that 5 years ago...

Comment: @riotburn and do I have to correct for multiple comparisons if I'll be using multiple dependent variables?

Comment: do you mean if you try different models?  If so, yes you would do those tests for each model because you don't know how new variables will interact.

Answer (score 0):

Regression sounds like a good starting place. You could also look at non-parametric methods like [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping).

It sounds like you might also be interested in data mining techniques if you're working with this kind of data. For example, if you have information about which products were bought together by the same customer, you can use the ["apriori association mining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) algorithm to find patterns. This method is often used to select the placement of pairs of items in stores, with a classic example being to put the diapers next to the beer (when new fathers are sent shopping alone, turns out they like to get a treat for themselves).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just one quick question concerning regression: how should I handle potential correlations between the factors, and is it a problem if I run multiple comparisons on the same dataset? do I need to correct for that somehow?

Comment: You can handle the corelations between the factors by including _interaction_ terms in your model when doing regression. This is done automatically in ANOVA. If you run multiple comparisons on the same data set, you need to correct for multiple hypothesis testing. There's a wiki page for it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons but, the simple answer is just to multiply your p-values by the number of tests you do.

Comment: thanks for your help, please have a look at my edited question, I've added a new problem

Comment: For the new problem, it seems like regression on the percentage of sales made up by the product at each store might work out.

Comment: but I don't know the exact amounts I only know that there are large differences in company size

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know the total amount of sales for each store, only that they are different for different stores?

Comment: yes, due to company size differences some companies only sold 5 some 100..

Comment: So that's fine, but do you know the total number of items sold be each shop?

Comment: I'll have to check but I think I only have that information for a few months... if it turns out that I DO have all this information, what can I do?

Comment: If you know the total number of items sold at each shop, you can use that value as a normalizing factor to determine what percentage of sales each type of item comprised at each shop. You can then ask questions about, for example, which types of items sell better in which shops.